# Why mobile CSS is not being used

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in `HEAD` to use different stylesheets for different device/screen size:

```
<!-- default stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css">

<!-- mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width : 320px)'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width : 320px)'>

<!-- if ie version 9 or less -->

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Inside the `defaultStyle_mobile.css` as a test, i added `*{display: none}` to make the entire page blank. I went here [http://www.responsinator.com/](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=) to view my webpage and it looks like the mobile stylesheet is not being used. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 media queries not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working)

Comment: `http://www.responsinator.com` url using iframe, So it normally using your web css not mobile css. in other words, it is not iphone simulator.

Comment: Not entirely duplicate as I am already using this line: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

Comment: @KrishR How about http://mattkersley.com/responsive/?google.com/about. That is also showing the web css instead of mobile css. Do I have to use the `@media` inquiring inside the .css file as well?

Comment: Yes. It also used the iframe

Comment: Why include min-width? Do you want your viewers to view the desktop CSS if they are on a screen with a width smaller than 320px?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Wow... seems like I have to create multiple stylesheets for multiple screen size to ensure it works around all devices.

Comment: Is it recommended to use % or PX when using position? I am predominantly using PX instead of percentage otherwise the images doesn't sit well with the layout.

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages to both `%` and `px`. It depends on the use, really. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/609561/2756409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your mobile stylesheets with these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)"     href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)'     href='theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css' />
```

If that's not the case, then the problem is with the simulator. Try resizing your browser.

Comment: Trying to figure out what is the difference... You is working.

Comment: Removed the 'only' directive in the media attribute :)

Comment: You also used the `max-width` property instead of `max-device-width`. These are two distinct properties and are calculated differently. PS, why the single quotes in the second line of your answer?

Comment: @SiKni8 see this answer for that information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996549/2756409

Comment: max-width is the width of the browser (did this to work with the simulator). max-device-width is the actual width of the device's screen. It is up to you, but using the first helps with development.