# Maintaining screen resolution when navigating between pages on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser, navigation

I have a very basic html site I created for my wedding: http://www.johnloveslesley.com/home.htm

I have never tried to create a mobile-adaptive website.  I don't feel the need to do so for this, really just a fun little practice project for me.

However, here is my question.  When I open the page on my iphone, and zoom in to look at the page - once I've navigated to a NEW page, the browser zooms back out.

Is there a simple code for maintaining the magnified navigation between pages?

Please let me know if I can be more specific with my question.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 media queries not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working)

Comment: To be more accurate you are looking for a way to keep a zoom on one page set by a user the same on the next page. If this is true then there is no simple way to do this (the suggest answer leave zoom=1 meaning none zoomed for each page)

Comment: The only possible ways I could see of doing this are with loading each page using ajax or doing some fancy javascipt in your GET request indicating the zoom and pre-setting the zoom again via the server or on page load with javascript

Comment: To clarify, brendos, there is no easy way to do this without fixing the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Please disregard AndyM's answer as it tells you a) that you can disabled zoom b) that it's terrible, but he doesn't care, and c) that you shouldn't care either, because people all want the same size of everything, and you shouldn't care about their opinion on zoom level. Disabling zoom seriously hurts UX.

Comment: @user3389837 Did it work? If so, you can accept my answer to tell future visitors that it worked for you.