# Media queries doesnt function?

Tags: css, media-queries

i m totally a newbie to responsive design. My media queries doesnt function. when i resize the window, it doesnt reconize the breakpoint i guess. i made two divs, one of them for desktop view and the other one is for the tablet view. I use the display: none property to have a desktop and mobile version.

Another question is, is there any way to configure media queries for all mobile devices ? or should i write css for every handy groups inviduel ? (like for iphone5, iphone6, nexus etc..)

```
.tablet-view{
    display: none;
}

.desktop-view{
    display: inline;
}
/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .desktop-view{
        display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .desktop-view{
display:none;
    }.tablet-view {

         display: inline;
     }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 media queries not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working)

Comment: i have  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> in my index.html, how it is dupplicate ?

Comment: What about the other suggestions? YOu've not provided much context here and its hard to know what it could be without all the facts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `device-width`. When you resize the window of the browser you don't change the width of the device thus the media query doesn't apply. Try on different devices or with the Chrome *device mode* in the  DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width` and `min-width` only without 'device'.