# Bootstrap 4 Beta display none/hidden issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am working with Bootstrap 4 beta via the CDN, and I am noticing an issue with the new d-* class.

I have a simply div with a class of "d-none d-lg-block" this works as expected, the div is only visible when the screen is above 992px.  However if I change the class to "d-none d-md-block", then no matter what I set the screen size to the div is always visible.

Is this a bug in bootstrap 4 beta?

Answer (score 0):

As of the bootstrap beta, the class "d-md-block" only has the below media query associated with it.

```
media (min-width: 768px)
  .d-md-block {
    display: block!important;
}
```

This ensure's that any element with the class "d-md-block" should always display on widths greater than or equal to 768px.

After testing this with the Bootstrap v4 Beta I can confirm that it's working as intended. Elements with "d-none d-md-block" are hidden for me in screens smaller than 786px using Chrome.

This is not a bug with the Bootstrap beta.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Don't think it is a bug in Bootstrap.  But perahps Chrome.  I just tested it in Safari, and it is working there.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that it appears that the bug may be when using the Toggle device tool in the dev tools.   When resizing the actually window, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What helped is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices)