# CSS Syling and color doesnt work on mobile browsers

Tags: css, html

I have a donate banner i have created for my site ..  it works fine on desktop [image]

But the color wont work on mobile browsers

[image]

Here is the code for the Donate Banner

```css
.Donate {
  background-color: #ffee00e3;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.PayPalClk {
  text-align: center;
}

.PayPalTxt {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2a2626;
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  display: block;
}

.PayPalbtn {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2a2626;
  /*Font styling*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffee00e3;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.700rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  /*End of font styling*/
  padding: 14px 60px 16px;
  background-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.550rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 38, 38);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Donate">
  <p class="PayPalTxt">Help us Raise Seed Capital In Order to improve our Products and expand our Team for a better Environment. <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></p>
  <div class="PayPalClk">
    <a class="PayPalbtn" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=2PE57UH79H8TY" target="_blank">Donate<i class="fa fa-gift"></i></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help or advise on how i could make it work would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: the text looks weird when it's on < 400px wide screen

Comment: have you tried adding this meta at the header of your html file ?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: Yea ... This is the tag i have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `background-color` on `.Donate` to **#ffee00e3** and not #ffee00 **(Should be in #RRGGBB format)**. 
This might cause undefined behavior since every browser will handle it differently. Some browsers might ignore the background-color altogether (like you are seeing on mobile browsers), or some browsers might be reading it as #ffee00 (which is the color you are seeing on desktop browsers), ignoring the last integer.