# CSS/HTML things. I can't resize my menu buttons for every screen

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in using HTML/CSS, but I started by editing different things to catch as little as possible. I have a problem. I was helped by a friend to create a menu, but it does not increase/shrink/center on the right side after each monitor/phone from which the site is accessed.

I don't know what to do first.

```
HTML

<!-- /Main navigation -->

</div>
</nav>

<div class="home-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="home-content">
                    <h1 class="white-text"><b>Adrian Vichiriuc</b></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</header>
<!-- /Header -->


<!-- Back to top -->
<div id="back-to-top"></div>
<!-- /Back to top -->

<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div class="preloader">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Preloader -->


<!-- jQuery Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Footer -->

<style>
    .footer {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="footer">
    <p style="font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:normal; text-align: center ">
        COPYRIGHT © 2019. SITE CREAT DE <span style="color: #07B425; font-weight:bold">ADRIAN VICHIRIUC</span></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
CSS

/*------------------------------------*\
    General
\*------------------------------------*/




/* --  Buttons  -- */

.main-btn, .white-btn, .outline-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.main-btn {
    background: #6195FF;
    color: #FFF;
}

.white-btn {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #10161A !important;
}

.outline-btn {
    background: transparent;
    color: #6195FF !important;
    border-color: #6195FF;
}

.main-btn:hover, .white-btn:hover, .outline-btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Logo
\*------------------------------------*/

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -350px;
}

.navbar-brand .logo, .navbar-brand .logo-alt {
    max-height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

#nav:not(.nav-transparent):not(.fixed-nav) .navbar-brand .logo-alt {
    display: none;
}

#nav.nav-transparent:not(.fixed-nav) .navbar-brand .logo {
    display: none;
}

#nav.fixed-nav .navbar-brand .logo-alt {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav.nav-transparent .navbar-brand .logo-alt {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #nav.nav-transparent .navbar-brand .logo {
        display: block !important;
    }
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Navigation
\*------------------------------------*/

#nav {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s padding;
    transition: 0.2s padding;
    z-index: 999;
}

#nav.navbar {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#nav.fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}

#nav.nav-transparent {
    background: transparent;
}


/* -- default nav -- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .main-nav li {
        padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    .main-nav li a {
        font-size: 14px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
        transition: 0.2s color;
    }
    .main-nav>li>a {
        color: #10161A;
        padding: 15px 0px;
    }
    #nav.nav-transparent:not(.fixed-nav) .main-nav>li>a {
        color: #000;
    }
    .main-nav>li>a:hover, .main-nav>li>a:focus, .main-nav>li.active>a {
        background: transparent;
        color: #6195FF;
    }
    .main-nav>li>a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: #6195FF;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0%;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s width;
        transition: 0.2s width;
    }
    .main-nav>li>a:hover:after, .main-nav>li.active>a:after {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* dropdown */
    .has-dropdown {
        position: relative;
    }
    .has-dropdown>a:before {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: "\f054";
        font-size: 6px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        float: right;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s transform;
        transition: 0.2s transform;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        right: -50%;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #6195FF;
        width: 200px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(53, 64, 82, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(53, 64, 82, 0.2);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(50%);
        transform: translateY(15px) translateX(50%);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
        transition: 0.2s all;
    }
    .main-nav>.has-dropdown>.dropdown {
        top: 100%;
        right: 50%;
    }
    .main-nav>.has-dropdown>.dropdown .dropdown.dropdown-left {
        right: 150%;
    }
    .dropdown li a {
        display: block;
        color: #FFF;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
        padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    .dropdown li:nth-child(1) a {
        border-top: none;
    }
    .has-dropdown:hover>.dropdown {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(50%);
        transform: translateY(0px) translateX(50%);
    }
    .has-dropdown:hover>a:before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    .nav-collapse {
        display: none;
    }
}


/* -- mobile nav -- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav {
        padding: 0px 0px;
    }
    #nav.nav-transparent {
        background: #FFF;
    }
    .main-nav {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        height: calc(100vh - 80px);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 80px 0px 0px #1C1D21;
        box-shadow: 0px 80px 0px 0px #1C1D21;
        max-width: 250px;
        width: 0%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
        margin: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #1C1D21;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
        transition: 0.2s all;
    }
    #nav.open .main-nav {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-nav li {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
    }
    .main-nav li a {
        display: block;
        color: #FFF;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
        transition: 0.2s all;
    }
    .main-nav>li.active {
        border-left: 6px solid #6195FF;
    }
    .main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:focus {
        background-color: #6195FF;
        color: #FFF;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .has-dropdown>a:after {
        content: "\f054";
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        float: right;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s -webkit-transform;
        transition: 0.2s -webkit-transform;
        transition: 0.2s transform;
        transition: 0.2s transform, 0.2s -webkit-transform;
    }
    .dropdown {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
        background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
    }
    .dropdown li a {
        padding: 6px 10px;
    }
    .has-dropdown.open-drop>a:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    .has-dropdown.open-drop>.dropdown {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
        transition: 0.2s all;
    }
}


/* -- nav btn collapse -- */

.nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.nav-collapse span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
}

.nav-collapse span:before, .nav-collapse span:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

.nav-collapse span, .nav-collapse span:before, .nav-collapse span:after {
    height: 4px;
    background: #10161A;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
}

.nav-collapse span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 10px);
    transform: translate(0%, 10px);
}

.nav-collapse span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -14px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, -14px);
    transform: translate(0%, -14px);
}

#nav.open .nav-collapse span {
    background: transparent;
}

#nav.open .nav-collapse span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-135deg);
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-135deg);
}

#nav.open .nav-collapse span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4px) rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-4px) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translateY(-4px) rotate(135deg);
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Header
\*------------------------------------*/

header {
    position: relative;
}

#home {
    height: 100vh;
}

#home .home-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}


.home-content button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.header-wrapper h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header-wrapper .breadcrumb {
    float: right;
    background: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header-wrapper .breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item.active {
    color: #868F9B;
}

.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
    color: #868F9B;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    About
\*------------------------------------*/

.about {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.about i {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #6195FF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.about:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s width;
    transition: 0.2s width;
}

.about:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.about h3 {
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.about:hover h3 {
    color: #fff;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Portfolio
\*------------------------------------*/

.work {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.work>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.work .overlay {
    background: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.work:hover .overlay {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.work .work-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.work .work-content h3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.work:hover .work-content h3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.work .work-content span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
    color: #6195FF;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.work:hover .work-content span {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.work .work-link {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.work .work-link a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #6195FF;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.work:hover .work-link {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Services
\*------------------------------------*/

.service {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 70px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
}

.service i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #6195FF;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.service:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s width;
    transition: 0.2s width;
}

.service:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.service h3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
  transition: 0.2s color;
}

.service:hover h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Why choose us
\*------------------------------------*/

.feature {
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
.feature i {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #6195FF;
    border: 1px solid #6195FF;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Numbers
\*------------------------------------*/

.number {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.number i {
    color: #6195FF;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.number h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Pricing
\*------------------------------------*/

.pricing {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 11;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.pricing::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s height;
    transition: 0.2s height;
}

.pricing:hover:after {
    height: 100%;
}

.pricing .price-head {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pricing .price-title {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.pricing:hover .price-title {
    color: #6195FF;
}

.pricing .price {
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    line-height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #6195FF;
}

.pricing .price h3 {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
  transition: 0.2s color;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.pricing:hover .price h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.pricing .duration {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #10161A;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.pricing:hover .duration {
    color: #fff;
}

.pricing .price-btn {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Testimonial
\*------------------------------------*/

.testimonial {
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.testimonial-meta {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 90px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.testimonial img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 70px !important;
    height: 70px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimonial h3 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.testimonial span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6195FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Team
\*------------------------------------*/

.team {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.team::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s height;
    transition: 0.2s height;
}

.team:hover:after {
    height: 100%;
}

.team-img {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 11;
}

.team-img>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.team .overlay {
    background: #1C1D21;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.team:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.team .team-content {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
}

.team .team-content h3 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.team .team-content span {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s color;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.team:hover .team-content h3 {
    color: #FFF;
}

.team:hover .team-content span {
    color: #6195FF;
}

.team .team-social {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.team .team-social a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #6195FF;
    color: #FFF;
}

.team:hover .team-social {
    opacity: 1;
}



.rainbow {

   /* Font options */
  font-size:40px;

   /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 3s infinite;

  /* Internet Explorer */
  -ms-animation: rainbow 3s infinite;

  /* Standar Syntax */
  animation: rainbow 3s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow{
  0%{color: orange;}
  10%{color: purple;}
    20%{color: red;}
  30%{color: CadetBlue;}
    40%{color: yellow;}
  50%{color: coral;}
    60%{color: green;}
  70%{color: cyan;}
  80%{color: DeepPink;}
  90%{color: DodgerBlue;}
    100%{color: orange;}
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes rainbow{
  0%{color: orange;}
  10%{color: purple;}
    20%{color: red;}
    40%{color: yellow;}
    60%{color: green;}
    100%{color: orange;}
}

/* Standar Syntax */
@keyframes rainbow{
  0%{color: orange;}
  10%{color: purple;}
    20%{color: red;}
    40%{color: yellow;}
    60%{color: green;}
    100%{color: orange;}
}

/* blog reply form */

.reply-form {
    margin: 40px 0px;
}

.reply-form form .input, .reply-form form .input , .reply-form form textarea {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.reply-form form .input, .reply-form form .input {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    display: inline-block;
}

.reply-form form .input:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Blog sidebar
\*------------------------------------*/

#aside .widget {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.widget h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* -- search sidebar -- */

#aside .widget-search {
    position: relative;
}

#aside .widget-search .search-input {
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#aside .widget-search .search-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #6195FF;
}

/* -- category sidebar -- */

.widget-category a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #354052;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 5px;
}

.widget-category a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
}

.widget-category a span {
    float: right;
    color: #6195FF;
}

.widget-category a:hover {
    color: #6195FF;
}

/* -- tags sidebar -- */

.widget-tags a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  color: #10161A;
}

.widget-tags a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #6195FF;
}

/* -- posts sidebar -- */

.widget-post {
    min-height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.widget-post img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.widget-post a {
    display: block;
    color: #10161A;
}

.widget-post a:hover {
    color: #6195FF;
}

.widget-post .blog-meta {
    display: inline-block;
}

.widget-post .blog-meta li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #6195FF;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.widget-post li i {
    color: #6195FF;
    margin-right: 5px;
}



/*------------------------------------*\
    Contact
\*------------------------------------*/

.contact {
    margin: 15px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact i {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #6195FF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.contact-form .input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.contact-form .input:nth-child(1), .contact-form .input:nth-child(2) {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.contact-form .input:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Footer
\*------------------------------------*/

#footer {
    position: relative;
}

.footer-logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.footer-logo>a>img {
    max-height: 80px;
}

.footer-follow {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-follow li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.footer-follow li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #6195FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

.footer-copyright p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
}

.home-content__main {
    padding-top: 24rem;
    position: relative;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Responsive
\*------------------------------------*/


@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-header h2.title {
        font-size:31.5px;
    }

  .main-btn , .default-btn , .outline-btn , .white-btn  {
        padding: 8px 22px;
        font-size:14px;
    }

  .home-content h1 {
        font-size:36px;
    }

  .header-wrapper h2 {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
  }

  .header-wrapper .breadcrumb {
      float: none;
      text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #portfolio [class*='col-xs'] {
          width:100%;
    }

  #numbers [class*='col-xs'] {
          width:100%;
    }

  .contact-form .input:nth-child(1), .contact-form .input:nth-child(2) {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .contact-form .input:nth-child(2) {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .reply-form form .input, .reply-form form .input {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .reply-form form .input:nth-child(2) {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }



  .blog-author .media .media-left {
      display: block;
      padding-right: 0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .blog-author .media {
      text-align: center;
  }
  .blog-author .media .media-heading .author-social {
      margin-top: 10px;
      float: none;
  }
  .blog-author .media .media-left img {
      margin: auto;
  }

  .blog-comments .media .media {
      margin:0px -15px;
  }
}



/*------------------------------------*\
    Owl theme
\*------------------------------------*/

/* -- dots -- */

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
    border: none;
    background: #EEE;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: #6195FF;
}
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span {
      background: #6195FF;
      width:20px;
}

.row {
    width: 94%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.row .row {
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

/* -- nav -- */

.owl-theme .owl-nav {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.owl-theme:hover .owl-nav {
    opacity: 1;
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: #6195FF;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}

.owl-theme .owl-prev {
    left: 0px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-next {
    right: 0px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-']:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: #6195FF;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Back to top
\*------------------------------------*/

#back-to-top {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6195FF;
    border-radius:3px;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#back-to-top:after {
    content: "\f106";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

#back-to-top:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Preloader
\*------------------------------------*/


#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.preloader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.preloader span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #6195FF;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-animation: 1s preload ease-in-out infinite;
            animation: preload 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
    border-radius:50%;
}

.preloader span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-delay: 0s;
}

.preloader span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
            animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.preloader span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
            animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

.preloader span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
            animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes preload {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform:scale(0);
               transform:scale(0);
    }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
            transform:scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
            transform:scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes preload {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform:scale(0);
               transform:scale(0);
    }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
            transform:scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
            transform:scale(0);
  }
}
```

I tried a few things but none worked, because I'm an nob.

Comment: can you post just the part which is having an issue, instead of complete site?

Comment: style tags go in the <head> section (or in the css seeing as you have a style sheet) Do you have a meta tag for the viewport set? (also in the <head> section).. ``<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`` . If you don't have a head section, add it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my CSS3 media queries not working on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices)