# Reactjs Media query application

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a separate App.css file that has global css attributes and have classes for responsiveness. The issue is I want to render elements differently for separate devices but can't seem to figure out how to do that as using conditionals isn't applying as such.

```
import UserItem from "./UserItem";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Users = ({ users, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle} className='body'>
        {users.map((user) => {
          return <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

Users.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const userStyle = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
  gridGap: "1rem",
};

export default Users;

My css @media query which I am trying to apply to effect change on a small device.

/* Mobile Styles */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .hide-sm {
    display: none;
  }
}

How do I implement this @media css style so that it can render the page differents through jsx?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use material ui. that will fulfil your requirement. Please check this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      backgroundColor: green[500],
    },
  },
}));

export default function MediaQuery() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">{'down(sm): red'}</Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">{'up(md): blue'}</Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">{'up(lg): green'}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Material UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/)

You can use following example too.

```
class Card extends Component {

  constructor() {

    super();

    this.mediaQuery = {
      desktop: 1200,
      tablet: 768,
      phone: 576,
    };

    this.state = {
      windowWidth: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.setState({windowWidth: document.body.clientWidth})
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{
        width: this.state.windowWidth > this.mediaQuery.phone
          ? '50%'
          : '100%',
        //more styling :)
      }}>
        <!-- <Card> contents -->
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Source](https://alligator.io/react/responsive-websites-without-css/)

Comment: I wanted to use the vanilla cs media classes that I already have. Can't that work?

Comment: @Mufasatoday, I have added another example. Please check whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Still not the response I wanted. I have a separate files with css media query class attached here - and I want to use those classes to render my page differently for different devices but only using my classes that I had defined.

Comment: @Mufasatoday is it helpful for you? https://medium.com/@ttennant/react-inline-styles-and-media-queries-using-a-custom-react-hook-e76fa9ec89f6

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use CSS `@media` query to make responsive layouts.
But if you insist on implement with JS and React you should get `windowWidth` after component mounted. You can use `useEffect` hook to do so and save value in a state:

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth) // or better one -> window.clientWidth
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this I am using CSS @media query already but I am applying them and they are not effecting any change. How do I do that?

Comment: @Mufasatoday I saw your edits. You could use classnames to add different styles under media queries. In your edit you define ".body" class but that one is not used in your components. Did you mean "body" HTML element? if so then you should use it without dot (.)

Comment: It shouldn't be ".body" I just changed it to see if it could apply any changes. I have been using className='hide-sm' which displays: none on small devices but it is not showing any changes. I have been applying it on the div that has style={userStyle}

Comment: @Mufasatoday Maybe you are not using media query in right way. Check [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working) answers.

Comment: I did find an a way of solving it. I used conditionals to render it using media query as a tag over it and it worked. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Mufasatoday You're so welcome. If you don't mind please rate my answer up and accept this answer using check mark icon.