# CSS - classes with media queries don't apply for elements in email templates

Tags: css, html-email

I am currently building an email template that needs to be responsive for mobile devices with appropriate text stylings and elements sizing. For example, when I apply a class for all **p** elements, I use class:

```
.mcnTextContent p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

And it perfectly works in resulting template.
But the problem is that if I try to use media queries and use classes like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

They don't apply to elements and in resulting email **p** elements have just standard font size.
Any help or suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Context is important. What email environment are you testing this in: Operating system, browser/app/program, version numbers? What other CSS do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />` to your html head class.
If it is still not working, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices).