# Inline CSS not following @media min-width and max-width properties

Tags: html, css, django

I am creating a pricing page in my Django app which has 3 columns. If the screen size is more than 768 pixels, I want it to show all 3 columns side-by-side. But if it's less 768 pixels, I want there to only be 1 column with the different pricing options on top of each other.

For some reason, the @media properties are not being followed. It doesn't matter what the screen size is, the page is always showing 3 columns. The below screenshot should only have 1 column (like most mobile-friendly pages)

**Current page:**
[image: Current mobile display]

**Js Fiddle** - [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/k62gquty/)
The strange thing is that in this JS Fiddle, it does seem to be following the `@media screen and (max-width)` properties.

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:800);

/* MOBILE CUSTOMIZATIONS */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .snip1214 .plan {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .snip1214 .plan {
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}




html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.snip1214 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 40px 10px;
}

.snip1214 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.snip1214 header {
  position: relative;
}

.snip1214 .plan-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #222f3d;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.snip1214 .plan-cost {
  padding: 0px 10px 20px;
}
.snip1214 .plan-price {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  color: #34495e;
}
.snip1214 .plan-type {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.snip1214 .plan-features {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: outside none none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.snip1214 .plan-features li {
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
  padding: 10px 5%;
}
.snip1214 .plan-features li:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.snip1214 .plan-features i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.snip1214 .plan-select {
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
}
.snip1214 .plan-select a {
  background-color: #222f3d;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.snip1214 .plan-select a:hover {
  background-color: #46627f;
}
.snip1214 .featured {
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 1;
}
.snip1214 .featured .plan-title,
.snip1214 .featured .plan-price {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.snip1214 .featured .plan-cost {
  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
}
.snip1214 .featured .plan-features li {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.snip1214 .featured .plan-select {
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

</style>

</head>


<body>
<div class="snip1214">


  <div class="plan">
    <h3 class="plan-title">
      Free
    </h3>
    <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$0</span></div>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>5GB Linux Web Space</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>5 MySQL Databases</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Unlimited Email</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>250Gb Monthly Transfer</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>24/7 Tech Support</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Daily Backups</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Select Plan</a></div>
  </div>


  <div class="plan featured">
    <h3 class="plan-title">
      Standard
    </h3>
    <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$3.99</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>25GB Linux Web Space</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>25 MySQL Databases</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Unlimited Email</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>2000Gb Monthly Transfer</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>24/7 Tech Support</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Daily Backups</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Select Plan</a></div>
  </div>


  <div class="plan">
    <h3 class="plan-title">
      Premium
    </h3>
    <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$6.99</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>100GB Linux Web Space</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Unlimited MySQL Databases</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Unlimited Email</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>10000Gb Monthly Transfer</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>24/7 Tech Support</li>
      <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Daily Backups</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Select Plan</a></div>
  </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860717/11261518 does this helps you ?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Yes it does, thank you! I added that and it now works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my CSS3 media queries not working on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to add this code in the `<head>` of my page

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Comment: no need to add your own solution. just accept the flag for duplicate.