# Why does my CSS look different on a mobile device than it does on my narrow desktop browser and how do I change it?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, mobile

Login-Screen on narrow Desktop-Browser:
[image: Login-Screen on narrow Desktop-Browser]

Login-Screen on mobile Device:

[image: Login-Screen on mobile Device]

Both sides have the same width and height and the exact same CSS-Code.
Why does it look different and how can I change it?

If i try using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px){ ... }
```

to change the width of the div it looks better on mobile but different and worse on Desktop.

Comment: do you mind posting your code for that element?

Comment: Check your meta tags

Comment: look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working-on-mobile-devices if that helps you understand what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very useful tag you can put in your head tag. Which is probably your issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use narrowing the desktop size for viewing your website in the mobile

Instead use the the mobile icon on the chrome developer tool in order to view what will appear on what screen size and accordingly use media query in CSS so that you can get what appearance you want on mobile.
[image: The second icon from the left]

Answer (score 1):

Try using  percentage instead of pixels and it should work.
One other thing you might consider is using bootstrap login pages.